Does it hold that $H^1(\Omega) = H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$ for $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R^2}$?
Suppose $\Omega$ is a locally Lipschitz and bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$, if a function $g\in H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$, then there exists a function $f\in H^1(\Omega)$ such that $f=g$ on the boundary $\partial\Omega$. Is the inverse statement true? (that is, if $f\in H^1(\Omega)$, is it true that $f\in H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$).
